# Calculation using radio group not working

Tags: java, android

i'm doing some project related to cafe menu and the calculation. i'm using a radio group for differentiate between 0% discount and 10% discount. When i click the radio button for 10% discount the code is working, but when i choose the radio button for the 0% discount the code isn't working. the result will be the same as 10% discount. Here's the code

```
package com.example.fo_liaharsono_proj_cafestekom;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView edHrgAyamG,edHrgAyamC,edHrgKentang,edHrgSoft,edHrgAir,edSubTotal,edStatus,edBayar;
    CheckBox cbAyamG,cbAyamC,cbKentang,cbSoft,cbAir;
    RadioGroup radioGroup1;
    RadioButton rgTunai,rgCredit;
    Button btnPesan;
    
    private boolean checked;
    private double dSubTotal;
    private double dBayar;
    private double dHrgAyamG;
    private double dHrgAyamC;
    private double dHrgKentang;
    private double dHrgSoft;
    private double dHrgAir;
    private double Diskon;
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edHrgAyamG = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edHrgAyamG);
        edHrgAyamC = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edHrgAyamC);
        edHrgKentang = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edHrgKentang);
        edHrgSoft = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edHrgSoft);
        edHrgAir = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edHrgAir);
        edSubTotal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edSubTotal);
        edStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edStatus);
        edBayar = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edBayar);
        
        cbAyamG = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbAyamG);
        cbAyamC = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbAyamC);
        cbKentang = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbKentang);
        cbSoft = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbSoft);
        cbAir = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbAir);
        
        radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rgTunai = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rgTunai);
        rgCredit = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rgCredit);
        
        btnPesan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPesan);
    
radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(rgTunai.isChecked())
            edStatus.setText("Pembayaran Tunai Diskon 0%");
        btnPesan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dSubTotal = (dHrgAyamG)+(dHrgAyamC)+(dHrgKentang)+(dHrgSoft)+(dHrgAir);
                Diskon = (dSubTotal*0)/100;
                dBayar = (dSubTotal-Diskon)*1000;
                edBayar.setText("Rp.  "+dBayar);
            }
        });
        if(rgCredit.isChecked())
            edStatus.setText("Pembayaran Credit Diskon 10%");
        btnPesan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dSubTotal = (dHrgAyamG)+(dHrgAyamC)+(dHrgKentang)+(dHrgSoft)+(dHrgAir);
                Diskon = (dSubTotal*10)/100;
                dBayar = (dSubTotal-Diskon)*1000;
                edBayar.setText("Rp. "+dBayar);
            }
            });  
            }
        });
        };          
        
    
    public void KlikCheckBox(View v){
        checked = ((CheckBox)v).isChecked();
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.cbAyamG:
            if(checked)edHrgAyamG.setText("15.000");
            else edHrgAyamG.setText("0");
            break;
        case R.id.cbAyamC:
            if(checked)edHrgAyamC.setText("12.000");
            else edHrgAyamC.setText("0");
            break;
        case R.id.cbKentang:
            if(checked)edHrgKentang.setText("10.000");
            else edHrgKentang.setText("0");
            break;
        case R.id.cbSoft:
            if(checked)edHrgSoft.setText("5.000");
            else edHrgSoft.setText("0");
            break;
        case R.id.cbAir:
            if(checked)edHrgAir.setText("3.000");
            else edHrgAir.setText("0");
            break;
        }
        dHrgAyamG = Double.parseDouble(edHrgAyamG.getText().toString());
        dHrgAyamC = Double.parseDouble(edHrgAyamC.getText().toString());
        dHrgKentang = Double.parseDouble(edHrgKentang.getText().toString());
        dHrgSoft = Double.parseDouble(edHrgSoft.getText().toString());
        dHrgAir = Double.parseDouble(edHrgAir.getText().toString());
        
        dSubTotal = ((dHrgAyamG)+(dHrgAyamC)+(dHrgKentang)+(dHrgSoft)+(dHrgAir))*1000;
        edSubTotal.setText(""+dSubTotal);
    }
}
```

i'm trying to figure out whats wrong but still can't find the answer

Comment: First off work on Your code, cause it is unreadable. What are those variablees? You're variable names tells us anything.

Comment: The `OnCheckedChangeListener` for `radioGroup1` either has two `OnClickListener`s with the 10% listener firing second, or only the listener for 10%, as written (depending on how this is works at runtime, I've never written anything for Android). Change your `if` statements to have their `then` clauses as blocks(`{}`) and this will be easier to see. Also, since you are using an IDE, you should consider not using Hungarian notation.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).